# How to use the updated state after setState call with react-hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How to use the updated state after setState call. In my below code, I am getting the previous state value.
For array below technique works.

setState(currentState => [...currentState, {name, value}]);

But for object, its not working.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
const [state, setState] = useState({});
const handleChange = e => {
  const { name, value } = e.target;
  setState(currentState => ({ ...currentState, [name]: value }));
  console.log(state[name]);
};
const handleSubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(state);
};
return (
  <div className="App">
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
     a
     <input
      type="text"
      name="a"
      value={state["a"] || ""}
      onChange={handleChange}
     />
     b
     <input
      type="text"
      name="b"
      value={state["b"] || ""}
      onChange={handleChange}
     />
     <button type="submit">Save</button>
   </form>
 </div>
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like: `setState({ ...state, [name]: value });` it should work for object

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `useEffect` to do something after the state is updated.

```
const [state, setState] = useState({});

...

useEffect(() => {
   console.log('Do something after state has changed', state);
}, [state]);
```

PS: This will run in the first render though.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look this code for your reference. https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-saha-q7h72

```
function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({ firstName: "", lastName: "" });

  const handleChange = e => {
    setState({ ...state, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="first name"
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={state.firstName}
        name="firstName"
      />
      <br />
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="last name"
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={state.lastName}
        name="lastName"
      />
      <hr />
      {state.firstName}--{state.lastName}
    </div>
  );
}
```